# How to get the speaking sound that comes from the phone user and convert to byte array ?

Tags: android

I writing simple application that need to make some record of the incoming sound. 
That mean that if the user will turn the record on => the application need to 'listen' what the user is saying and convert the sound of the user to byte array and save the byte array to some file ( mp3 format ) .

I don't finding any way to get the sound that coming from the user ..

Someone can help me with this issue ?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Performing Audio Capture
>
> ```
> Create a new instance of android.media.MediaRecorder.
> Set the audio source using MediaRecorder.setAudioSource(). You will probably want to use MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC.
> Set output file format using MediaRecorder.setOutputFormat().
> Set output file name using MediaRecorder.setOutputFile().
> Set the audio encoder using MediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder().
> Call MediaRecorder.prepare() on the MediaRecorder instance.
> To start audio capture, call MediaRecorder.start().
> To stop audio capture, call MediaRecorder.stop().
> When you are done with the MediaRecorder instance, call MediaRecorder.release() on it. Calling MediaRecorder.release() is always recommended to free the resource immediately.
> ```

Example and source can be found here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/audio-capture.html

Answer (score 1):

You could also use AudioRecorder if you need other things and codecs (for example raw pcm 16 bit). 
With AudioRecorder you get directly the bytes which you can process like you want (ie converting to mp3 codec yourself).

Anyhow I think you should explain what exactly you want to do.. ie if you like to process the audio for speech recognition mp3 is not what you want.